# how can PDFminer loop in a folder with 1-3 pages long PDFs, transform them in Txt and save them in a separate folder?

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer

My code is able to loop in my folder, read pdf, transform to text and save in a new folder; but it does not read more than the first page (PDF with more than 1 page show an error) and some files are saved with PDF spaces (l i k e  t h i s). any advice?

If I run this same code in individual files instead of doing the loop in a folder, it does read the whole PDF (one page or longer).

Here is my code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("AA_banxico_pdfs/"):
    for filenames in files:
        try: 
            rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
            retstr = io.StringIO()
            codec = 'utf - 8'
            laparams = pdfminer.layout.LAParams()
            setattr(laparams, 'all_texts', True)
            device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
            interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
            password = ""
            maxpages = 0
            caching = True
            pagenums = set()
            print("Processing file: " + str(filenames))
            fp = open("AA_banxico_pdfs/" + filenames, 'rb')

            for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenums, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
                interpreter.process_page(page)
                text = retstr.getvalue().replace('\n', ' ')
                filenameString = str(filenames) + ".txt"
                text_file = open("banxico_txts/" + filenameString, "w")
                text_file.write(text)
                text_file.close()
                fp.close()
            device.close()
            retstr.close()
        except: 
            print("failed" + str(filenames))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way creating a path and the running the loop, in case anyone needs it:

```
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue().replace('\n', ' ')

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
```

And then:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("banxico_pdfs/"):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        try:
            text_file = open("banxico_txts/"+filename+".txt", "w+")
            text_file.write(convert_pdf_to_text("banxico_pdfs/"+filename))
            text_file.close()
            print(filename+" done")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(filename+" failed to complete")
```